# Angular Change Page through Child Component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using Angular 6, I want to change the Component Title from "NOT VERIFIED" to  "VERIFIED" whenever "SAVE" button is clicked.

The problem I'm facing is that the "SAVE" button is being operated through another component. So how do I update Page title from the other component?

[image]

I have tried using `BehaviourSubject`, but still facing issue.

Here's the sample code for `BehaviourSubject` that I'm using:

```
export class ComponentTitleService {
  componentTitle = new BehaviorSubject < string > ('');
  title = this.componentTitle.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
  updateTitle(title: string) {
    this.componentTitle.next(title);
  }
}
```

Parent Component with TITLE:

```
this.componentTitleService.title.subscribe(title => {
  this.componentTitle.next(title);
});
```

The component that Updates Title:

```
this.componentTitleService.title.subscribe(title => {
  let newTitle: string = title;
  newTitle.replace("NOT VERIFIED", "VERIFIED");
  this.componentTitleService.componentTitle.next(newTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct use for your service:

```
export class ComponentTitleService {
  private componentTitle = new BehaviorSubject < string > ('');
  public title = this.componentTitle.asObservable();
  constructor() {}

  updateTitle(title: string) {
    this.componentTitle.next(title);
  }
}
```

Some component which use title:

1) Add Service as public to constructor:

```
...
constructor(public titleService: ComponentTitleService)
...
```

2) In your template use async pipe:

```
<h2>{{ titleService.title | async }}<h2>
```

Some component which updates title. **You don't need to change title inside component, just send new title to service**

```
 someMethod(){
     ...
     this.componentTitleService.componentTitle.next(newTitle);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to subscribe to title observable to call next function. Just call `this.componentTitleService.componentTitle.next(newTitle);` to update the title.
In your snippet, since you subscribe to title observable and update the title in the callback, it is never called since your title never emits a value.

you only need a subject and a titleComponent to display the value of that subject through async pipe. then call subject's next method from any location you want to update the title. See this small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv1rrj